# Quasi-isometric rigidity of surface groups and commensurability

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group quasi-isometric to the fundamental group of a genus 2 surface group $H$.  It is well known that $G$ is quasi-isometrically rigid, i.e. $G$ and $H$ are virtually isomorphic.  Does the stronger property, that $G$ and $H$ are commensurable, also hold?

If so is there a reference for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes (I assume that by "virtually isomorphic" you mean commensurable modulo finite kernels, which is a nonstandard misleading use of "virtually"). This is because surface groups have Serre's property D$_2$ meaning that each 2-cohomology class (in a finite abelian group with trivial action) it trivial on some finite index subgroup.

(Also a side remark: the known result on QI rigidity is stronger, since it says that every group QI to this surface group is, modulo a finite kernel, isomorphic to a cocompact lattice in the isometry group of the hyperbolic plane. I.e., there's a structural statement which does not require passing to a finite index subgroup.)

Comment: Serre calls this property $D_2$ in Cohomologie galoisienne (I.2.6) (or at least it seems to me to be equivalent).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda thank you, I've edited accordingly!

Comment: (Just to elaborate about "misleading": for instance "virtually torsion-free" means that some finite index subgroup is torsion-free. The property that some finite index subgroup modulo some finite normal subgroup is torsion-free, is strictly weaker.)

Comment: Yes virtually covirtually isomorphic would be better terminology but for whatever reason virtually isomorphic seems to be the standard usage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @SamHughes It might be "standard" among a few authors in the last few years, but the use of "virtually" in a consistent meaning has been existing for a longer time and by a much larger community.